# Python File Exists

Tags: python, file, file-exists

I'm new to python and just can't seem to get the code I'm writing to carry on processing if a file doesn't exist in the directory I point it to. Basically, I'm opening each text file to make a small amendment. I've tried putting the (what I thought) is the correct code here

```
for filename in find_files('a-zA-Z0-9', '*.txt'):
if os.path.isfile(filename):
```

with an else at the end of the code which prints a messge file not found. But I still get an IOError no such file or directory, which brings the whole program to a stop. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: plz share the complete code. Without knowing what find_files() actually does it's hard to help.

Comment: how comes find_files returns a file that does not exist ? are you deleting it from elsewhere ? in this case, you have a synchronization issue. Your file could be deleted after the test, but before you open it (just like it can be deleted after the find_file, but before the test isfile)

Comment: what does find_files do, btw ?

Comment: @njzk2 < this, usually you should attempt to open the file and catch the exception in a `try` `except`, avoiding race conditions

Comment: `isfile()` doesn't throw that exception, so it is either coming from your `find_files()` function or you are trying to work on a file even if `isfile()` returns `False`. Or you have a sync issue. Post more complete code for more help

Comment: anyway: fix your indentation as well, in your code: you should indent the if-statement.

Comment: I think you can find an answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-with-python

Answer (score 0):

i dont know your "find_files" function but os.path.isfile() just returning a False even if the given path is invalid

```
>>> os.path.isfile("NOTEXIST:/really/not/exists")
False
```

Error must be in your "find_files" function.

Comment: very sorry for the poor examples so far.